# NSIS Plugin Function not recognised

Tags: c++, dll, nsis

I have made a very simple NSIS plugin that has one function in it. I have successfully compiled the Win32 DLL project into a DLL then copied it to the directory *C:\Program Files (x86)\NSIS\Plugins*

**My Problem:** When I create .nsi script that calls a function from the dll I get a compile error saying *Invalid command: tbox::myFunction*

What am I doing wrong? **Do I need to copy the tbox.lib file to the NSIS directory aswell or create a tbox.nsh file to include?**

My dll's name is tbox.dll, my nsi script is below and below that is my C++ DLL code:

```
    !include MUI2.nsh
    !include WinMessages.nsh

    Name    "aa.nsi"
    OutFile "aa.exe"
    Caption "${^Name}"
    ShowInstDetails show
    !define MUI_CUSTOMFUNCTION_GUIINIT   MyGUIInit

    Section "Dummy"
        MessageBox MB_ICONINFORMATION|MB_OKCANCEL "dvkjdkj"
        tbox::myFunction "abc" "def"
    SectionEnd
```

DLL Code:

```
#include "targetver.h"
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "msimg32.lib")
#include <commctrl.h>
#include "TransparentCheckbox.h"
#include "NSIS/pluginapi.h"

HINSTANCE g_hInstance;
HWND g_hwndParent;
unsigned int g_stringsize;
stack_t **g_stacktop;
TCHAR *g_variables;

// To work with Unicode version of NSIS, please use TCHAR-type functions for accessing the variables and the stack.
HWND __declspec(dllexport) myFunction(HWND hwndParent, int string_size, TCHAR *variables, stack_t **stacktop, extra_parameters *extra)
{
  g_hwndParent=hwndParent;
  EXDLL_INIT();

  {
    TCHAR buf[1024];
    wsprintf(buf,TEXT("string_size=%d, variables=%s\n"), string_size, variables);
    MessageBox(g_hwndParent,buf,0,MB_OK);
  }

  return g_hwndParent;
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HANDLE hInst, ULONG ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
  g_hInstance = (HINSTANCE)hInst;
  return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Can you see the exported function from other tools eg Depends?

Comment: @leppie yes I can see the function and its name but its a little weird for some reason ?myFunction@@YAPAUHWND__@@PAU1@HPADPAPAU_stack_t@@PAUextra_parameters@@@Z

Comment: You need to export it as a C function. The answer given is correct. Use `extern "C"`.

Comment: The function should probably return void, not HWND...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Makensis lists all plugins and their exported functions when you compile.

If your plugin is not listed then it is not in the correct directory or has no exports at all. If it is listed but has the wrong name (`tbox::_myFunction` or `tbox::myFunction@xyz`) then you have a decoration problem. You can try `extern "C" HWND __declspec(dllexport) __cdecl myFunction(...`, if that is not enough you might need a [.def](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d91k01sh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) file.

You can also take a look at the exports with [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)...

Comment: thanks for the reply: it says my functions name is "?myFunction@@YAPAUHWND__@@PAU1@HPADPAPAU_stack_t@@PAUextra_parameters@@@Z" is that correct? Never worked with dll's before

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load plug-in in current script directory use this command:

```
 !addplugindir "."
```